How can I create TikZ annotations with arrows and braces for parts of a formula?
I am using TikZ to annotate a mathematical formula with arrows and braces. My goal is to create the following annotations:

A green arrow from above pointing from an instance of a quantifier to the overbrace marking its scope within the same formula.
A strikethrough red arrow from below pointing from another quantifier to the underbrace marking a non-scope.

For reference, here is an example of what I’d like to achieve for the first case:

Here is the code I have so far:
$$\begin{tikzpicture}[inner sep=0cm,baseline,anchor=base,>=latex,decoration=brace]
    \node (scope-1-forall) {$\phantom{y}\forall x \,$};
    %
    \node [right=0cm of scope-1-forall] (scope-1-inside) {$(P(x) \wedge Q(y))$};
    %
    \node [right=0cm of scope-1-inside] (scope-1-and) {$\,\wedge\,$};
    %
    \node [right=0cm of scope-1-and] (scope-1-outside) {$S(x,b)$};
    
    % Overbrace
    \draw[decorate,blue]
    ($(scope-1-inside.north west)+(0.3ex,0.2ex)$) -- ($(scope-1-inside.north east)+(-0.3ex,0.2ex)$);
    
    % Underbrace
    \draw[decorate,blue,decoration={brace,mirror}]
    ($(scope-1-outside.south west)-(0ex,0.2ex)$) -- ($(scope-1-outside.south east)-(0ex,0.2ex)$);
    
    % Green Arrow
    \draw[->,teal,transform canvas={yshift=.5ex}]
    (scope-1-forall.north) to[out=30,in=150] ([yshift=.5ex] scope-1-inside.north);
    % [xshift=-1ex, yshift=-.5ex]
    
    % Red Arrow
    \draw[->,red,transform canvas={yshift=0ex}]
    (scope-1-forall.south) to[out=-20,in=-150] ([yshift=-1ex] scope-1-outside.south);$$

I'm using the following:
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,decorations.pathreplacing,calc}

This provides the image above, but without the strik in the red arrow.
I welcome totally aalternative approaches to accomplish this. Ideally, I’d like to:

Keep the entire formula within a single block.
Assign dedicated labels to the braces so that arrows can reference them directly.
Perhaps placing a text above the green arrow ('scope') and below the red arrow ('non-scope').

While I’ve come across posts addressing parts of this problem, I find it challenging to combine the solutions as I’m still new to TikZ.

Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for the users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Here's a solution using the equation environment from the amsmath package to annotate your equation and the tikzpicture for drawing. Here's the first solution I came up with using regular text above/below the arrows:

Here's the code:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz, amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings, tikzmark, arrows.meta}

\begin{document}

% Mathematical expression along with nodes to remember
\begin{equation*}
    \tikzmarknode{fa}{\forall} x \ {\color{blue}\tikzmarknode{obrace}{\overbrace{\color{black}(P(x) \land Q(y))}}} \land \color{blue} \tikzmarknode{ubrace}{\underbrace{\color{black} S(x, b)}}
\end{equation*}

% Actual drawing part
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    % Arrow and text for the overbrace 
    \draw[-{Latex[round]}, shorten < = 1pt, green!50!black] ([yshift=2pt]fa.north) to[out=30, in =150, looseness=0.9] node[above, text=blue] {scope} (obrace.north);

    % Arrow and text for the underbrace
    \draw[-{Latex[round]}, shorten < = 2pt, red,
    postaction = decorate, decoration = {markings, mark = at position 0.5 with {\draw[-] (0,-1.6mm) -- (0, .6mm);} } ] ([yshift=-1pt]fa.south) to[out = -30, in=-150, looseness = 0.8] node[below, text=blue] {non-scope} (ubrace.south);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

The above example does the job of placing the text above and below the arrows, but I personally think text bending along the arrows would look better. Thus, I created another example with that using the decorations.text library:

Here's the code:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz, amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings, tikzmark, arrows.meta, decorations.text}

\begin{document}

% Mathematical expression along with nodes to remember
\begin{equation*}
    \tikzmarknode{fa}{\forall} x \ {\color{blue}\tikzmarknode{obrace}{\overbrace{\color{black}(P(x) \land Q(y))}}} \land \color{blue} \tikzmarknode{ubrace}{\underbrace{\color{black} S(x, b)}}
\end{equation*}

% Drawing with bent text
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    % Arrow and text for the overbrace 
    \draw[-{Latex[round]}, shorten < = 1pt, green!50!black,
    postaction={decoration={text along path, text={|\color{blue}|scope},
    text align={align= center}, raise=1mm}, decorate}] % bent text
    ([yshift=2pt]fa.north) to[out=30, in =150, looseness=0.9] (obrace.north);

    % Arrow and text for the underbrace
    \draw[-{Latex[round]}, shorten < = 2pt, red,
    postaction = decorate, decoration = {markings, mark = at position 0.46 with {\draw[-] (0,-1.6mm) -- (0, .6mm);} }, % marking
    postaction={decoration={text along path, text={|\color{blue}|non-scope},
    text align={align= center}, raise=-2.5mm}, decorate}] % bent text
    ([yshift=-1pt]fa.south) to[out = -30, in=-150, looseness = 0.8] (ubrace.south);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

The decorations libraries can be confusing to deal with, and I'd strongly suggest you check out their documentation if there's something you don't understand. My usage of the libraries comes from there.

Another possibilities with use of the ext.paths.ortho library and rounded line corners beside tikzmark library:

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                ext.paths.ortho,
                tikzmark,}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[66]
\vspace{3ex}

    \[
\tikzmarknode{a}{\forall} x
    {\color{red}\overbrace{\color{black}(P(x)\land Q(y))}^{\tikzmarknode{b}{}}}
    \land 
    {\color{blue}\underbrace{\color{black}S(x,b)}_{\tikzmarknode{c}{}}}
\tikz[overlay, remember picture,
      arr/.style = {color=#1, -{Straight Barb[scale=0.8]}, 
                    semithick, rounded corners},
      every node/.append style = {midway, inner ysep=2pt, align=center}      
      ] 
{
\draw[arr=cyan]     (a.north) r-ud [ud distance=7pt] (b.south)
                            node[above] {label};
\draw[arr=orange]   (a.south) r-du [du distance=7pt] (c.north) 
                            node[yshift=-4pt] {$\Vert$\\ label};
}
    \]

\vspace{5ex}
\lipsum[66]
\end{document}


\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,arrows.meta,decorations.markings,fpu}
\begin{document}
\begin{gather*}
    \text{some math}\\[1ex] % space this manually
    \tikzmarknode{a-1}{\forall} x
    {\color{red}\overbrace{\color{black}(P(x)\land Q(y))}^{\tikzmarknode{a-2}{}}}
    \land {\color{blue}\underbrace{\color{black}S(x,b)}_{\tikzmarknode{a-3}{}}}\\[1ex] % space this manually
    \tikz[overlay, remember picture,/pgf/fpu/install only={reciprocal}] {
        \draw[-Latex,cyan] (a-1.north) to[out=90,in=135] (a-2.center);
        \draw[
            -Latex
            ,orange
        ] (a-1.south) to[out=-90,in=-135,looseness=0.4] (a-3.center);
        \draw[
            ,decoration={
                markings
                ,mark=at position 0.4 with {\draw[orange] (0,-2pt) -- (0,2pt);}
            }
            ,decorate
        ] (a-1.south) to[out=-90,in=-135,looseness=0.4] (a-3.center);
    }
    \text{some math}
\end{gather*}
\end{document}


